# How can I make simulated logistic regression model more noisy?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, simulation

When I want to simulate Y coming from the linear regression model,
$$Y_i = X_i ^T \beta + \epsilon_i,$$

I can use code like:

```
x = rnorm(100); beta = 1
y = x %*% beta + rnorm(100, sd = 3)
```

If I want to make the estimate of $\beta$ "noiser" (increase standard error), I can increase the standard deviation in the second line above.

How can I increase the standard error of a logistic regression coefficient? I can simulate from a logistic regression model with:

```
x = rnorm(100); beta = 1
nu = x %*% beta        # linear predictor
pr = 1/(1+exp(-nu_1))         # pass through an inv-logit function
y = rbinom(100,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable
```

Comment: `nu = x %*% beta + rnorm(100,0,1)` would do it, altering the standard deviation as required.

Comment: @jbowman's approach works well, but--unlike the ordinary least squares case--it renders the model invalid by introducing "overdispersion."  Whether that's a problem depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your simulation.

Comment: I think @whuber's comment holds the key to getting a good answer - what is your ultimate objective?  Why are you trying to make the estimate of $\beta$ "noisier"?  Does bias matter? ...

Answer (score 1):

You could make the $x \times \beta$ values be on average substantially below (or above)  zero instead of approx. zero (e.g. subtract 2 from all x values). That results in a more unbalanced data set.

Or you could reduce the number of observations. Or you could add additional covariates to the model that also need to be estimated.